# File upload message succes but no file into folder

Tags: php, forms, image, file-upload

I wanted to create a PHP code that allows me to upload a photo to my website. The problem is first time I clicked the upload button, the message was " Succes" but no file into my folder, and second time I didnt change the code, it throws me and error message. Can you please look over and tell me if I did something wrong?

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
     $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
     $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
     $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg','png');
    if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if($fileError === 0){
            if($fileSize < 2048000){
               $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = 'uploads/images'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                header("Location: profile.html?upload=succes");

            } else {
                echo "Your file is too big!";
            }
        } else {
            echo " There was an error uploading your file!";
        }

    }else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }
}
```

I got the error "There was an error uploading your file " .

HTML FORM

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                     <span> Change Profile Picture</span>
                     <input class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" type="file" name="file"> 
                     <button class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
                   </form>
```

When i hit the print_r($file);
 It throws me `Array ( [name] => IMG_6389.jpg [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 )

` I got the error 1 instead of 0

Comment: without seeing the HTML/form, it's hard to say what's failing. In either case, enable error reporting then tell us what the real cause/error is.

Comment: So far, `uploads/images` is a typo since it's missing a trailing slash. `uploads/images'.$fileNameNew` will interpret that as `uploads/imagesIMAGE.xxx` as opposed to `uploads/images/IMAGE.xxx`.

Comment: please don't post code in comments, edit the question instead. But my 2nd comment was edited, so reload it. Which to me is all it is.

Comment: I edited that, but I still got the "there was an error uploading your file "

Comment: again; enable error reporting to see why it failed you. Maybe your file is larger than the allowed max or the folder doesn't have proper write permissions.

Comment: The image is less than 2GB and I have the error for that, I think it's a problem at  inarray()

Comment: `'uploads/images'.$fileNameNew;` that still reads without the slash `'uploads/images/'.$fileNameNew;`. I don't know what else to say. I don't see error reporting neither or where you're doing `print_r()`. You'll have to wait for someone else who sees something I don't.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll wait!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of filesize. You have to increase the maximum size of an uploaded file in php.ini.

Error 1 is UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in
>   php.ini.